# Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is function such that $f^3$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$ and that $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $f^3$ is continuous, we can choose $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta$ we have that $\rvert f^3(x) - f^3(c) \lvert < \epsilon$.

To show that $f$ is continuous, I know I need some number $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta_1$ implies that $\lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert < \epsilon$.

I've tried manipulating the expression $\lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert < \epsilon$ by using the fact that $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$. I get 
$$
  \lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert < \frac{\lvert f^3(x) - f^3(c)\rvert}{\lvert f^2(x) + f(x)f(c) + f^2(c) \rvert} < \frac{\lvert f^3(x) - f^3(c)\rvert}{\lvert f^2(x) + f(x)f(c) \rvert}.
$$
However, I am not sure how to continue and I am also not confident that this is a good way to approach the exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that the best way is to use the fact that the function $x\mapsto\sqrt[3]x$ is continuous. So,$$f^3\text{ continuous}\implies\sqrt[3]{f^3}\text{ continuous}\iff f\text{ continuous.}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Right.  Note also that $f^2$ continuous does **not** imply that $f$ continuous: consider the function that is $1$ on the rationals and $0$ on the irrationals.  So the issue of when $x^n$ has an inverse function seems to enter in crucially: blindly pushing around inequalities is probably not the way.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I suppose that you meant that $f$ is $-1$ on the irrationals.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Yes, thank you.